# How to fix the postion of splitDividerView in NSSplitViewController

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssplitviewcontroller

How to fix the postion of splitDividerView in NSSplitViewController
I had been search for years,but it doesn't work.Please help,Thanks!
Once this app start,the left view width is 150,but still i can resize both of the left and right view by dragging the splitDividerView. I have attatached a screenshot for reference

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.splitView.wantsLayer = true
        self.splitView.setPosition(150, ofDividerAt: 0)

    }
```

[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLO8K.png)

Comment: Where is the divider in the image? Do you want to make it impossible to slide the divider? Why do you use a split view?

Comment: Yes , i want to make it impossible to slide the divider , and what other kinds of UIObject recommend beside NSSplitController to display to ViewController?

Comment: Two views side by side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add two container view which is use for managing NSViewController , so get rid of NSSplitView and will save you hours
[image: ScreenShot for Reference]